Usual navigation motions in a popup window?
I'd like to write a file-tree/file-browsing plugin that uses popup windows.
In popup_create I can set a filter to capture keys. For instance,
popup_create('hello world', {filter: 'popup_filter_menu'})

uses one of the builtin filters that captures j, k, <Esc>, etc.
On the other hand, suppose I somehow create a temporary buffer numbered bufnr with a nicely formatted file-tree. Then I know I can set the popup window to display this tree with
popup_create('', {})->popup_setbuf(bufnr)

But is there a way to expose this window to the usual navigation motions like gg, G, 10j, etc.? Kind of like how netrw and NERDTree operate in regular buffers. Or is the only way to achieve this by writing a (relatively complicated) custom filter function?


No, not for +popupwin. Say, in Neovim floating windows are more or less normal windows but popups in Vim are not.

Yes, but it doesn't worth. If you need gg and such then abandon popups and switch to standard windows/buffers.



That's unfortunate & agree it wouldn't be worth the time and complexity to add things like gg manually.
